# Why isn't my canvas clearRect working?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I set up an interval:

```
tick = setInterval(function(){
    render();
}, 1000 / 25)
```

Then each `render()` I clear rect and expect to see a dot travel across the screen.

```
function render() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    circle(sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.r);

    for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
        var s = animations[i];
        if( s.target ){
            Engine.Animate(s);
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason, I'm ending up drawing every single position of the dot, rather than just one.

[image]

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/yvmbsjj1/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the canvas context that you are starting a path, and then your clearRect will work. Use the [beginPath() method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beginpath.asp) to do this.

```
function render() {
        ctx.beginPath(); // This is needed 

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

        circle(sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.r);

        for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
            var s = animations[i];
            if( s.target ){
                Engine.Animate(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is needed when drawing lines, arcs, circles, rectangles, etc...
And should be called every time you render, to initialize a new path.